# Variable erase in foreach when concatenating

Tags: php, variables, foreach

I have looked over the internet for this but the problem only occurs with somebody when trying to pass an array to foreach and alter it inside. My problem is much easier and confusing.
I have 2 global variables:

```
$type="";
$rule="";
```

And i have this code:

```
foreach($cartasxml->children() as $child) {
    $str="insert into cards (title,cost,color,loyalty,type,pow,tgh,hand,life,rules,set,rarity,number,artist,flavor,cost) values('{{{".$child->name."}}}',";
if(isset($child->typelist))
    {
        foreach($child->typelist as $a)
            $type .= "|" . str_replace("{","[",str_replace("}","]",$a->type));
        $str.="'{{{".substr($type,1)."}}}',";
    }
    else
        $str.="NULL,";
```

And at the end of foreach i do:

```
$type="";
$rule="";
```

So, when i see the value of $type by printing $str it only shows the last one i included. Maybe an escope problem, but i still don't know how to solve it.

Somebody?

Comment: Can you add some return values to your code plz? What kind of string does $type contain in foreach?

Comment: Each time through the loop you initialize `$str`. Why do you expect to see anything more than the last one when you're done?

Comment: @Barmar if you look closelly you'll see that i clear the string just on the outer foreach. Thats because i wanna concatenate the ->typelist of the current ->children not the whole ->typelist of all ->children

Comment: @ArmelL. The concatenated string should have returned: Creature|Shaman and only returns Shaman

Comment: There must be a problem in your data structure... Can you try to print $a->type inside the foreach block to check for 2 passes? Did you do it already?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `print_r($cartasxml);`?

Comment: @ArmelL. I've solved my problem using a function to clear the string outside the foreach, with &$var. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use array to push all the values into it

```
$type_array = array();
$str_array = array();
foreach($cartasxml->children() as $child) {
    $str="insert into cards (title,cost,color,loyalty,type,pow,tgh,hand,life,rules,set,rarity,number,artist,flavor,cost) values('{{{".$child->name."}}}',";
if(isset($child->typelist))
    {
        foreach($child->typelist as $a)
            $type .= "|" . str_replace("{","[",str_replace("}","]",$a->type));
        $str.="'{{{".substr($type,1)."}}}',";

array_push($type_array,$type);
array_push($str_array,$str);

    }
    else
        $str.="NULL,";


print_r($type_array);
print_r($str_array);
```

Comment: Mate, already done that. used and array and then, when before concatenate i imploded the var. Same issue. Maybe some PHP config here in my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$type = implode('|', 
                array_map(function($a)
                           { return str_replace("{","[",str_replace("}","]",$a->type)) },
                          $child->typelist));
$str .= "'{{{".$type."}}}',";
```